# Hibernate with ddl-auto: update always alters some fields

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a spring-boot project with spring data.
My application.yml contains this property:

```yaml
spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
```

Every time I run the project, Hibernate executes ALTER TABLE statements for **date**, **enum** and **float/double** fields.

Hibernate show_sql logs:

```
Hibernate: alter table activity_data modify column points  float(53)
Hibernate: alter table activity_event modify column end_time  datetime(6)
Hibernate: alter table activity_event modify column start_time  datetime(6)
Hibernate: alter table giveaways modify column state  enum ('CREATED','ENDED','GOING') not null

... and some more
```

It doesn't really affect the project or cause any bugs, but it does bother me, and may be causing the application to start slower

Do you know any configuration that disables it? Maybe it happens because hibernate can't tell if these column settings are up to date?

One of the things I tried for the *double* fields, I tried manually setting a manual value to the column scale:

```java
@Column(name = "POINTS", scale = -1)
private double points;
```

but it changed nothing

Comment: Seeing similar issue after updating to hibernate 6.2. Any luck on resolving this?

Comment: Notice the data types are so specific. meaning it's either float(53) or datetime(6) due to java.util.Date. my observations are only meant as a hint, i am not sure this is the case, but my experiments suggest so.

Comment: seems to be related to https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/schemamigrator-wants-to-alter-my-columns/7697

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and it seems that we are lucky (the bad kind) because is an weird/rare and ancient issue:

https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/manytoone-alter-table-query-is-generating-every-time-when-inserting-a-value/1162

I overcome this problem by simply updating the hibernate version to **6.2.8.Final**, I also tried **6.3.0.Final** and it works fine too.

The tested versions that present this issue are from **6.2.0.Final** to **6.2.7.Final**

The weird thing is that i have other project that have the exactly the same configuration, versions of everything and running almost the same code, i even run it in the same machine, in the same application server, in the same IDE but the second project does NOT present the issue with **6.2.6.Final** version, nether with previous or later versions.

Both project uses **JPA 3.1**

Happy Coding;

Comment: I have the same problem also with 6.2.8.Final. I have empty database, it creates all tables and indices and then wants to alter columns.. weird.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered a similar issue as well, but it happened when I upgraded from Spring Data JPA 3.0.x to 3.1.x. It seems to be caused by the upgrade in the Hibernate version in the dependencies. In my case, I update fields of type 'date,' 'text,' and 'json,' and indeed, the application startup is quite slow. It also performs updates every time it starts. I'm not sure yet what changes Hibernate made.
However, until we know of a solution, you can temporarily downgrade the Spring Boot version to 3.0.9.

Answer (score -5):

If you don't want to change the database on startup
You can set the property in application.yml like this:

```
ddl-auto: none
```

Or when you need to check the mapping with tables and entities

```
ddl-auto: validate
```

However, these properties mean that you will have to manually create a table when adding a new entity.