# Hibernate alters tables even though entities are unchanged

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm working on a Spring Boot project that uses Hibernate for ORM, and in my `application.properties` I have `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` set to `update`.

This setting is convenient for updating the database schema when my entity classes change.

However, I've noticed that Hibernate generates ALTER statements for all columns, including those that haven't changed in my entity classes. This causes the app launch slower since it's altering every table unnecessarily.

Here is an example output I am receiving:

```
Hibernate: 
    alter table document_comments 
       modify column created_at  datetime(6)
Hibernate: 
    alter table documents 
       modify column content  json
Hibernate: 
    alter table documents 
       modify column created_at  datetime(6)
Hibernate: 
    alter table documents 
       modify column status  enum ('ACTIVE','ARCHIVED','DELETED')
Hibernate: 
    alter table documents 
       modify column updated_at  datetime(6)
```

and the list goes on.

I am using Java 17, Spring 3.1.2 and Hibernate 2.6

Comment: that seems to be the known issue: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76509211/3426309

Answer (score 0):

If a column must be changed is a decision of hibernate himself.

Hibernate read the type from the JDBC-Driver and compare this type with the type in the Entity. If Hibernate recognize a difference, hibernate try to solve the difference using this alter-table DDL update-commands. Hibernate might not update the type successfully (because the type already set).

There are 3 reasons why hibernate think a change might help:

1. The value-range of the reported database-type from the jdbc-driver differs from the value-range of the java-field-type.
2. The jdbc-driver report wrong values (might be a bug in the jdbc-driver).
3. The dialect of the sql-database does not match the jdbc-driver.

A flip-flop problem might be a bug in hibernate, this happens if the type is changed from one type to a differenct type.

You could try to:

1. Try to use the latest jdbc-driver.
2. Try to correct the hibernate-dialect.
3. Try to use a more matching entity-field-type.
4. Try to use the latest hibernate version (transient dependencies accordingly).

From a architect point-of-view:

Well, there is a principle called single-version-of-truth (SVOT). It points out that either the DB hold the 100% truth of the datastructure OR the entities. This might give the hint that the DB always right in terms of field-type-savety. This guides you to modify the entities until it matches the DB perfectly.